# How to get to know what ports are taken?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am creating a simple learning project (chat using sockets) in Java and today I faced a problem. Maybe the point is an obvious one for somebody, but I am confused with it

### The purpose

To get to know (at least one of the following):

1. A list of the currently opened free/taken ports on a PC
2. Whether the port I want to use is locked

### What I tried

I've created a simple raw-project and run two `ServerSocket` on one port. In this case I have caught a `java.net.BindException` with notification that "...Address already in use: JVM_Bind...". But in this way I am able to check the port avaliability only if my JVM has captured it. In case if other program listens to the port, I do not know anything about it. I am adding a code below.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5940);
        myThread.start();
        serverSocket.accept();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5940);// exception is thrown here
            serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("SECOND SERVER");
            e.printStackTrace();
            interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

PS Any advice is warmly welcomed

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why do you think you need a list of free ports? And what do you mean by 'port is locked'?

Comment: What is the purpose of your `interrupt();` call? Side issue -- don't extend Thread but rather implement Runnable or Callable depending on the need.

Comment: For the question in the title: for a server you cant realy detect and adjust as the client needs to know to which port to connect otherwise it won't find the server. You can however make it configurable or do some discovery(add 1 to the port until you get something free and do the same in the client until you get a connection). The latter is rather odd - but you find it every once in a while.
For a client on the other hand you simply bind to port 0 and the machine will assign one port from the ephemeral range(something that is free).

Comment: And 'currently opened free' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 3):

> I've created a simple raw-project and run two `ServerSocket` on one
>   port. In this case I have caught a `java.net.BindException` with
>   notification that "...Address already in use: JVM_Bind...". But in
>   this way I am able to check the port avaliability only if my JVM has
>   captured it. In case if other program listens to the port, I do not
>   know anything about it.

I think you're misinterpreting your result.  I have every reason to believe that if the port you request is already bound by *any* process then your attempt to bind it will fail with a `BindException`.  That takes care of

> 2. Whether the port I want to use is locked

. As for

> 1. A list of the currently opened free/taken ports on a PC

, there are system utilities that can get you that information, but it is useless to you.  Whichever end initiates the connection (i.e. the client) needs to know in advance what port to try to connect to.  It cannot get that from the server, because that presents a chicken & egg problem.

The usual approach is that the server listens to a specific port chosen by its developer or its admin, and that port number is provided to clients out of band -- often simply by it being a standard, well-known port number.  That's how most of the basic network protocols work; for example, HTTP servers run on port 80 by default.  If the wanted port happens to be unavailable when the server attempts to bind to it then that indicates a misconfiguration of the machine, and the server simply fails to start.

The client, on the other hand, does not need to choose a port number at all.  The system will choose one for it automatically when it attempts to connect to the server.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As far as I understood from:
_...I have every reason to believe that if the port you request is already bound by any process then your attempt to bind it will fail with a BindException..._
it is possible to listen two or more ports by different processes. Am i right?

Comment: @MikeBiri, either the same or different processes may listen to *different* ports at any given time, but no two processes may listen to the *same* port at the same time.  Nor can even a single process have multiple sockets listening to the same port at the same time.

Comment: That is the problem I am talking about. For example, my Skype client listens the port 8080, at tha same time I am able to create a `ServerSocket` in the JVM and set it to listen port 8080. And no exception will be thrown...

Comment: @MikeBiri, then Skype must be listening to ***UDP*** port 8080.  Your Java server is definitely listening to a ***TCP*** port.  The two are independent and do not conflict with each other.